# I am changing my email address from Comcast to Gmail and need to email everyone who ever emailed me

Tags: gmail

I know this will not be an easy task, but a friend informed me that he used a service that emailed everyone who ever emailed him at a college email address to notify them of his new email address. I have searched online for days and cannot find what he was talking about.

My original account is with Comcast, and contacts are not automatically saved (unlike Gmail which saves every contact that I email to "other" to await proper filing). Anyone have some ideas? Obviously I could send a message to everyone in my contacts - but I only have about 20 saved.

Comment: If he was having a college email address, it is possible the college had a `mail-all` address, like a mailing list.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I need to send an email to everyone I've ever sent mail to](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8921/i-need-to-send-an-email-to-everyone-ive-ever-sent-mail-to)

Comment: I don't know about Comcast, but I shut off my Cox services awhile ago, while my email was set to auto-forward to my new address, and it continued to auto-forward for years after my service ended. If that's true for Comcast too, you can just let those messages come in and get auto-forwarded, then have rules in your new email box that either auto-replies with the new info, or filter the messages into a separate inbox so that you can manually inform the senders about your new address.

Answer (score 1):

I havent tested this and its not the easiest, but it could get the job done. Its also not exact instructions, but more a suggested way of achieving what you are after. (This also would only work if you can access your comcast email via imap. )

1. Download and install [IMAP Backup](http://www.broobles.com/imapsize/imap-backup.php)
2. Configure the backup to use the `from:` field as the filename of each email backup (configurable in the Options/Misc dialog)
3. Use the command prompt to save a list of all .eml files to a text document.
4. Import into a excel spreadsheet & remove duplicates. Thats your list.

You could potentially do this with the to: field instead of the from: field aswell. Its not a great method as you have the backup all your emails which could take some time, but at least you dont have to manually go through all the emails :p

Answer (score -1):

If Comcast has Auto Replies, just set one indefinitely with your new email address in the message. Its like Out Of Office replies.

Option 2 - Forward your emails from Comcast to Gmail. Start replying with your new Gmail email address.